# Intellij IDEA probably don't detect methods of described_class in specs

Tags: ruby, rspec, intellij-idea, static-methods, rubymine

I have a class:

```
class A

  def foo
    1
  end

  def self.bar
    2
  end

end
```

I have made a spec for it:

```
describe A do

  describe '#foo' do
    expect(subject.foo).to eq 1
  end

  describe '::bar' do
    expect(described_class.bar).to eq 2
  end

end
```

I use IntelliJ IDEA 14 with ruby plugin, but I think this is the same also for RubyMine.
When I type `subject.`, the autocomplete works and offers the method `foo`. But for `described_class.` it does not work. I think it should offer the method `bar`.

The same issue applies for clicks. When I click on `foo` in `subject.foo`, I am redirected to the correct method. But when I click on `bar` in `described_class.bar`, the fulltext search is performed and I am offered all methods in all classes with that name.

Am I missing something or is it a bug in IDEA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug (or, rather, a missing feature) in the Ruby plugin; its code insight does not have any special recognition for the described_class method.

I wasn't able to find an existing YouTrack issue for this problem, so you're welcome to [file your own](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RUBY).